# Trying to get a specific number of characters from a list of characters which then pass the random function

Tags: python, for-loop

First of all I would like to point out that I am JUST STARTING to learn to code, so I apologise if my question is downright asinine(which I'm sure it will be) but either way I could use some help from those kind souls who don't mind helping a complete noob out.

So as a starter project into python I thought I would write a random password generator that takes the following inputs - 
1. Number of characters(minimum being 6)
2. Number of UpperCase Characters
3. Number of LowerCase Characters 
4. Number of Numeric Characters(0-9)
5. Number of Special Characters

I'm facing two issues:-
1. While I am getting output it isn't the specific number of characters that I input.
2. The output always comes with [''] (As a list)

I'm not too worried about 2. as I've already seen some answers about using the join function to remove the brackets.

My main worry is running a for loop(Any other ideas more than welcome) to run the number of times the user inputs so that the random function can choose the specified amount of characters

Any and all help appreciated.

Here's the code:-

for l in range(lower):
    lower_pass = random.choices(lower_list)

Output example:-
       ./pass_gen2.py 
How many characters would you like?:9
How many upper case characters?:3
How many lower case characters?:3
How many digits?:2
How many Special Characters?:1
[[0], ['>'], ['R'], ['y']]

Answer(Full credit to @Arume):-

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7

#Password Generator Attempt 2
import random

characters = int(input("How many characters would you like?:"))

if characters >= 6:
    pass
else:
    print("Minimum charachter length is 6")
    exit()

upper = int(input("How many upper case characters?:"))
lower = int(input("How many lower case characters?:"))
digits = int(input("How many digits?:"))
spec_characters = int(input("How many Special Characters?:"))

tot_char = int(upper) + int(lower) + int(digits) +int(spec_characters)
if  tot_char == characters and int(upper) >= 1 and int(lower) >= 1 and int(digits) >= 1 and int(spec_characters) >= 1:
    pass
else:
    print("The total number of characters does not match what you had selected or one of the character types is set to 0")
    exit()

#upper_list = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z']
#lower_list = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g,','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z']
#digit_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
#spec_characters_list = ['!', '@', '#', '$', '%', '^', '&', '*', '(', ')', ':', ';', '<', '>', '?', '|', '/']

pass_list = []

for u in range(upper):
    upper_pass = random.choice("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    pass_list.append(upper_pass)
for l in range(lower):
    lower_pass = random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    pass_list.append(lower_pass)
for d in range(digits):
    digit_pass = random.choice("0123456789")
    pass_list.append(digit_pass)
for s in range(spec_characters):
    spec_characters_pass = random.choice("!@:;#$%^&*,<>?|/")
    pass_list.append(spec_characters_pass)

random.shuffle(pass_list)
password = "".join(pass_list)
#print(upper_pass, lower_pass, digit_pass, spec_characters_pass)
print("Your random password is:", password)
```

Comment: Welcome welcome. Please, format your code using [https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). And [Minimal Reproducable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It'll greatly help us help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not understand what you have trouble with but I tried writing three examples. Try executing them.

1. An Example using `random.choice` functions. This is lengthy but easy to understand.

```
import random

number_all = int(input("How many characters would you like? : "))

if number_all < 6:
    print("The total number of characters must be 6 or more!")
    exit()

number_upper = int(input("How many upper case characters? : "))
number_lower = int(input("How many lower case characters? : "))
number_digit = int(input("How many digits? : "))
number_special = int(input("How many Special Characters? : "))

if number_all != number_upper + number_lower + number_digit + number_special:
    print("The figures do not add up!")
    exit()

characters_list = []

for _ in range(number_upper):
    upper = random.choice("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
    characters_list.append(upper)

for _ in range(number_lower):
    lower = random.choice("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
    characters_list.append(lower)

for _ in range(number_digit):
    digit = random.choice("0123456789")
    characters_list.append(digit)

for _ in range(number_special):
    special = random.choice(",.;:()[]-+=")
    characters_list.append(special)


random.shuffle(characters_list)
password = "".join(characters_list)
print(password)
```

2. An Example using `random.choices` functions. This is a little elegant.

```
import random

number_all = int(input("How many characters would you like? : "))

if number_all < 6:
    print("The total number of characters must be 6 or more!")
    exit()

number_upper = int(input("How many upper case characters? : "))
number_lower = int(input("How many lower case characters? : "))
number_digit = int(input("How many digits? : "))
number_special = int(input("How many Special Characters? : "))

if number_all != number_upper + number_lower + number_digit + number_special:
    print("The figures do not add up!")
    exit()

characters_list = []

upper_list = random.choices("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", k=number_upper)
characters_list.extend(upper_list)

lower_list = random.choices("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", k=number_lower)
characters_list.extend(lower_list)

digits_list = random.choices("0123456789", k=number_digit)
characters_list.extend(digits_list)

special_list = random.choices(",.;:()[]-+=", k=number_special)
characters_list.extend(special_list)


random.shuffle(characters_list)
password = "".join(characters_list)
print(password)
```

3. An Example using a `random.choices` function and a `for` statement. This is more elegant.

```
import random

number_all = int(input("How many characters would you like? : "))

if number_all < 6:
    print("The total number of characters must be 6 or more!")
    exit()

number_upper = int(input("How many upper case characters? : "))
number_lower = int(input("How many lower case characters? : "))
number_digit = int(input("How many digits? : "))
number_special = int(input("How many Special Characters? : "))

if number_all != number_upper + number_lower + number_digit + number_special:
    print("The figures do not add up!")
    exit()

characters_and_numbers_list = (
    ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", number_upper),
    ("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", number_lower),
    ("0123456789", number_digit),
    (",.;:()[]-+=", number_special),
)
characters_list = []
for characters, number in characters_and_numbers_list:
    picked_list = random.choices(characters, k=number)
    characters_list.extend(picked_list)

random.shuffle(characters_list)
password = "".join(characters_list)
print(password)
```

Comment: This is EXACTLY what I was looking for! It worked brilliantly only needed to add the append to the code. Thanks a ton! Will try out the other two tomorrow if I get time.

Comment: All of them are working perfectly. Thanks again @Arume